# Embedding of $S_3$ in $S_6$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-homomorphism

Prove or disprove: There exists an embedding of $S_3$ in $S_6$ as transitive subgroup.

Half proof(attempt): Let $\phi : S_3 \longrightarrow S_6$ that sends cycle $\tau$ in  $S_3$ to $S_6$ , For example $\phi (1,2,3)= (1,2,3)$ (but in S_6) , It is a homomorphism. Now, define $X=\{(x_1,...,x_6)|x_4=4,x_5=5,x_6 =6,x_1,x_2,x_3\in \{1,...,3\}\}$ and the action of $Im(\phi)$ $\forall g\in Im(\phi)$   :
$$ \sigma.x= (\sigma(x_1),\sigma(x_2), \sigma(x_3), x_4,x_5,x_6) $$

Let $x,y\in X$, Here I'm struggling to show that it is transitive.

Comment: This follows immediately from Cayley's theorem.

Comment: @DerekHolt What does it have to do with the transitivity?

Answer (score 2):

$S_3$ acts on itself transitively by multiplication.

Comment: I don't understand how the Image of phi is $S_3$ itself.

Comment: This is the action defined in the proof of Cayley's theorem, which is usually one of the first results people learn in group theory.

Answer (score 0):

Every group $G$ embeds by left multiplication into the symmetric group of its underlying set. Explicitly, the map is $\varphi\colon g\mapsto(x\mapsto gx)$. In fact:

- $x\mapsto gx$ is injective by the left cancellation law and surjective by the existence of $g$'s inverse;
- $g\mapsto()$ is operation-preserving by the associative law;
- $g\mapsto()$ is injective by the right cancellation law.

Note that, given $x,y\in G$ and set $g:=yx^{-1}$, we get $\varphi_g(x)=y$, and hence $\varphi_G\cong G$ is a transitive subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(G)\cong S_{|G|}$. Now, take $G$ as your $S_3$ to get the claim.

For an example of a non-transitive embedding of $S_3$ into $S_6$, for $\sigma\in S_3$ define $\varphi_\sigma$ as the only permutation on $\{1,\dots,6\}$ defined by:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\varphi_\sigma(i):=\sigma(i),\text{ for }i=1,2,3 \\
&\varphi_\sigma(i):=i,\text{ for }i=4,5,6 \\
\end{alignat}
As an instance, no one $\varphi_\sigma$ "connects" $1$ and $4$, so $\varphi_{S_3}$ in not transitive on $\{1,\dots,6\}$.